# Problems to use packages in Go

Tags: go, package

I'm having problems to use packages. I a following literally the steps I find online, but I have an error message.

I have this package in GOPATH:

go/src/greet/day.go

```
package greet

var morning = "Good morning"
var Morning = "hey" + morning
```

I want to import it in my code:

go/src/app/entry.go

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "greet")

func main(){
    fmt.Println(greet.Morning)
}
```

When I run entry.go, I receive this message:
entry.go:4:3: package greet is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/greet)

Does anybody how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: GOPATH is outdated. Use modules instead. https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module

Comment: Read [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code).  The tutorial shows how to use packages.

Answer (score 1):

GOPATH isn't really used anymore. You can use a different directory and run `go mod init greet`. This will create a new module "greet" in that folder, and from within that module you can import packages using import "{module name}/{package path}". It is a best practice to use the folder name as the package name, so the import path matches the folder names (except for main packages).

Additionally, if your module lives in a git repository, your module name should be the path to the git repository. for example, `go mod init github.com/jaenmo/myrepo`.

within your module make a folder for your main package. You should be able to import using your module name.

Comment: Thank you for your help PotatoesFall. I tried and still didn't work.
The problem was on the settings of VS Code. A friend could change it and now works perfectly.

Thank you!